# Is it possible to do input multiple values for the calendar DayOfWeek parameter?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-calendar

Essentially, I am creating an alarm app, and would like to use the setAlarmClock method instead of setRepeating to set an alarm that recurs every day (or if possible select days) using a calendar instance. I am wondering if you can set the DAY_OF_WEEK parameter to multiple values, or a variable containing a list of values.
My code would look something like this:

```
AlarmManmager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, 0);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, //some variable with multiple day values here);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 2);
AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo ac= new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(c.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
```

Help is much appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TimesSquare library and CalendarPickerView for choosing multiple dates as presented here at [GitHub](https://github.com/square/android-times-square).

Basically with this library, you can choose multiple dates inside one CalendarPicker and get all selected dates as a list of dates.

Comment: I understand, but I want this alarm to ring on certain days of the week using the setAlarmClock method in alarm manager, not days of a month